# If a java class have to methods of the same name but one has static and the others dont which one does it execute?

Tags: java, methods

```java
public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        int y = 5;
        System.out.println(a.foo(y));
    }
}

class A{
    public A() {
        
    }
    public int foo(int x) {
        return x+1;
    }
    public static int foo(int x) {
        return x+2;
    }
}
```

If a java class has two methods of the same name but one has static and the other doesn't which one does it execute? Why does it prioritize the one on top? Or is it because the first foo does not have static?

Comment: execute your code and figure it out. However, you should realize that the code you posted will never compile, let alone execute

Comment: I executed my code and it did run as the output I got was 6. I am wondering why is the output 6 and not 7. Is it simply because the first foo method is ontop of the second or because of the static keyword?

Comment: you did not execute the code you posted, because that code can not be compiled.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally added a public encapsulation to the class A

Comment: which is not related to the issue I was referring to

Comment: Ok I understand now, the second duplicate method will never execute because it is missing a return value. But after adding a return value of int, it still only executes the top foo method, is that because of the order of the method?

Comment: that is not the only problem - it still should not compile without error - from Java Language Specification [8.4.2. Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2-200): "**It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with override-equivalent signatures in a class.**"  and some sentences earlier: "Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types."

Comment: **1 -** the posted code never was executed (why do you state so? copy&paste error? wrong code/version being executed?)  **2 -** the whole question is pointless

Comment: Your code does not compile: https://ideone.com/chUxMG

Answer (score 1):

Java language specification , is very clear about it. Static and non-static methods can overload each other.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9

> If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or
> both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the
> same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the
> method name is said to be overloaded.

Though in your example , it will be compile error since signature is same (nt foo(int x)).

The following is complete valid.

```
public int foo(int x){
        return x;
    }

    public static float foo(float y){
        return y;
    }
```

IMO,  Practically its not a good practice to have mixed overloading (static and non-static)

Comment: yes, that is valid code, but it is not the code in the question. This answer has nothing to do with the actual question.

Comment: Please go through my answer again... already commented on his code. It will be compile error that is why No question of prioritising over here.

Comment: the question was: which one will be executed. Not whether or not overloading is valid. The overloading he showed is not valid. It's for his code he wants the answer, not for code that looks slightly similar to his code

Comment: There is no question which will be executed since its compile error.  It better to provide answer from your perspective , if you think context is different , rather being judgemental on others.

Comment: questions will never be executed. But, indeed, that is the point. The code about which the question is, won't be executed, so there is no order for this specific case. Your answer is based on different types of parameters, which doesn't match the question. It's not being judgmental to point out that that is not in line with the question.

Answer (score 0):

If It is of same name and one is static and other isnt, It will not work
If Both Functions Have Different parameters then if you call the function it will try to match the arguments given with the parameters in both same name functions. and will call the functions which have exact same arguments.
NVM my English

Comment: If both have the same name and the same parameter. Does it still call the method based on priority?

Comment: @Beier By Java Language Specification, that is not allowed ("same name and same parameter")